# Render Block from an array of blocks - Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I need to render blocks somehow from a list of blocks i get with the following function:

```
const applyWithSelect = withSelect((select, blockData) => {
    const parentClientId = select('core/block-editor').getBlockRootClientId(
        selectedClientId
    );

    return {
        innerBlocks: select('core/block-editor').getBlocks(blockData.clientId),
    };
});
```

So here, I have innerBlocks as an array of blocks on that page that looks like this (first element):

```
0:
attributes: {title: "Enter Title", review: "Enter review", rating: "Add Rating", reviewerName: "Enter Name", reviewDate: "Enter Date", …}
clientId: "2413142124"
innerBlocks: []
isValid: true
name: "something/some-item"
originalContent: "<div>something</div>"
```

Is there a way for me to use this innerBlocks variable in my edit function, and just somehow render the block? The reason for not using `<InnerBlocks >` is that I have to render them one by one, so each block is a separate element in my slider. I would need something like this:

```
const reviews = this.props.innerBlocks;

return (
   <div>
       <div className="carousel">
           <Slider {...slickSettings} className={classnames(this.props.className)}>
               { reviews.map((block, i) => {
                    return (
                        block.render() // this line is the issue, doesn't have to be render, but
                                       // any other way of rendering block separately from InnerBlocks
                         )

                 })
               }
           </Slider>
       </div>
   </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling to get something similar for a while now. What I needed was just to return a string of the rendered block with `renderToString` but I think you can easily remove that and just return the block itself.

After digging into [WordPress's repo](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/inner-blocks/test/index.js), I think the answer has to do something with the function `getSaveElement( nameOfBlock, attributesObject, [optionalInnerBlocks] )`

my code looks somthing like this:

```js
import { registerBlockType, getSaveElement } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { renderToString } from '@wordpress/element';

const arrayOfInnerBlocks = something.innerBlocks; //for example purposes
const getRenderedEl = ( attributes ) => {
    const el = renderToString(
        getSaveElement( 'core/cover', attributes ) //this is the main thing!
    );
    return el;
}

// i'm deconstructing the innerBlock item and just getting attributes.
const blockElements = arrayOfInnerBlocks.map( {attributes} => ({ individualBlock: getRenderedEl(attributes) }) )
```

So for you, something like this:

```js
const reviews = this.props.innerBlocks;
const getRenderedEl = ( {attributes, name} ) => getSaveElement( name, attributes ); //this is the main
return (
   <div>
       <div className="carousel">
           <Slider {...slickSettings} className={classnames(this.props.className)}>
               { reviews.map( getRenderedEl ) }
           </Slider>
       </div>
   </div>
)
```

hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: I'm looking to solve a very similar issue. What Andres suggests kinda works, but not exactly ideal as it doesn't give you the ability to then select each individual inner blocks and trigger editor controls such as the Inspector, Toolbar, etc. 

Have you guys found a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You show blocks in edit function using **BlockEditorProvider**, use map function to list all arrays and inside it show the elements in value attributes. You can detect changes in **onChange** and **onInput** if you need them.

```
<BlockEditorProvider
    value={ block[ index ] }
    onInput={ ( state ) => {
        console.log( state );
    } }
    onChange={ ( state ) => {
        const newBlockContent = block.concat( [] );
        newBlockContent[ index ] = state;
        setAttributes( {
            myBlocks: newBlockContent,
        } );
    } }
>
    <SlotFillProvider>
        <BlockTools>
            <WritingFlow>
                <ObserveTyping>
                    <BlockList />
                </ObserveTyping>
            </WritingFlow>
        </BlockTools>
        <Popover.Slot />
    </SlotFillProvider>
</BlockEditorProvider>;
```